# Swift 2 passing data through segue from UIcollectionview (indexpath.row)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to pass data (value of dict["IDD"] ) via segue.
(XCODE 7.2)

Here my code:

```
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() 
var dict = [:] 

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell

    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]

    let newPrice = dict["price"]!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: ",")

    cell.lblPrice.text = "€\(newPrice)"
    cell.lblTitle.text = dict["title"] as? String
    cell.lblBrand.text = dict["brand"] as? String
    cell.lblIDD.text = dict["IDD"] as? String

    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "loading.gif") //set placeholder image first.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        cell.imageView!.downloadImageFrom(link: dict["image"] as! String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit) //set your image from link array.
    }

    return cell
}
```

But I don't kwon how to setup the performseguewithidentifier for segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "homeDetailSegue")
    {
        let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
        let detailView = segue.destinationViewController as! dettaglio
        let dict = arrRes[(self.myCollectionView.indexPathForCell(cell))!]
        detailView.setnomeOggetto(arrRes["IDD"] as! String)
    }
}
```

I have no problem with tableviews but this is my first time with collectionView

Could please someone help me?

Kind Regards
Thank You very Much
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution for your question and now I got it.Try below the solution.

Before that go to stroyborad click the destinationViewController(here detailViewController)

```
Then click Identity Inspector of the Right Navigation bar.
Once you click the you can see the Identity under Custom Class
No click Identity then give 'detailsVC' or whatever you want in Storyboard ID.
```

Now in CollectionViewDelegate Method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailVC") as! DetailViewController
    detailVC.passDataToLabel = String (indexPath.item )
    print(detailVC.passDataToLabel)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank You for the answer, but Could be possible to use the same method used for a tableview?
Here my example (it works for tableview)

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "homeDetailSegue")
        {
            let datoDaPassare = segue.destinationViewController as! dettaglio
            let dict = arrRes[(self.tblJSONHOME.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
            
            datoDaPassare.setnomeOggetto(dict["id"] as! String)
            
        }
    }

Thank You